# Youtube Player API results in java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar, youtube

When I add the Youtube Player API jar file (1.2.1 or 1.2.2 - didn't tested older), it seems that the JVM cannot find most of my classes at runtime.

For example, when I add the JAR file, this error is thrown:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.estudiotrilha.view.PatchedScrollingViewBehavior
...
```

If I stop using this class, this error is thrown:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.estudiotrilha.inevent.R$styleable
...
```

What I suspect is that when I add the JAR file, for some reason, the reference to some classes disappear (maybe for lack of space?). I'm just guessing, but the project is indeed really huge, I'm already using multidex.

PS: when I remove the JAR file, everything works fine.

Also, I'm not even using the library, just adding the jar file to my libs folder and compiling it within my app, it breaks.

Here is my **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion sdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion btVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.estudiotrilha.inevent"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 101
        versionName "3.1.5p3"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            /* hidden */
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {

        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {

        whiteLabelFlavor {
            applicationId "us.inevent.apps.whiteLabel"
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':libraries:view-pager-indicator')
    compile project(':libraries:CropImage')

    // ExtendView library
    compile 'com.mauriciogiordano:extendview:1.0.2'

    // Design support libraries (Google)
    compile androidSupport.appcompat
    compile androidSupport.cardview
    compile androidSupport.gridlayout
    compile androidSupport.recyclerview
    compile androidSupport.design

    // Design support libraries (third-party)
    compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'

    // RecyclerView animators :)
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.3.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.5.3'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

    compile (httpcomponents.mime) {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }

    compile httpcomponents.client
}

task appStart(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'installWhiteLabelFlavorDebug') {
    // linux
    commandLine 'osascript', '-e', 'display notification "Your manual build has finished!" with title "Build completed"'
}
```

Comment: do these missing classes belong directly to your project or come from dependencies?

Comment: Belongs directly to my project, same package... Actually it's in the same file... A class is not finding an inner class from same file

Comment: well, I guess it is something android specific, I've never seen such a thing in java applications

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the entire build folder fixed the problem...